# Multiple Google Contact Books at once

Tags: android, google-chrome, gmail, google-contacts-api, google-account

Is there any way to search for a google contact for multiple google accounts at the same time? (PC/Browser)

I have a few different accounts that I use for business and they all have different contact groups. In Android devices it is possible to add all google accounts to the same address book, so this kind of a search is possible.

Comment: Aside from writing your own app, where you read in all the contacts for each account on the device, the only other way that comes to mind would be to [export contacts](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/24911?hl=en) for each account and [import](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/14024?hl=en) them into one.

Comment: I was expeting something this simple to have an already existing solution. :(